# Accessing web camera in WebView2 from Local html/js file

Tags: uwp, webview2

I have created a Javacsript which access Web Camera and it works fine in Chrome and Edge . And also works fine WPF with WeBView2 .
But I try to use same javascript in UWP with WebView2 then nothing works , looks like permission issue in webview2 for my local Htmlfile .

I tried below code (someone posted ) but it has also not worked

```
if (wv2.CoreWebView2 != null)
{
        wv2.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
            "appassets.example1", "Assets",
            Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.DenyCors);
        try
        {
            wv2.Source = new Uri("http://appassets.example1/camera.html");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

How can I give permission or map properly in in UWP? My html file is in Assets folder:

```
C:\Users\xyz\Documents\uwp_LiveVideo_Blur\uwp_LiveVideo_Blur\Assets\cam.html
```

Comment: Did you enable the camera in the package manifest capabilities section? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

Comment: any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

> Accessing web camera in WebView2 from Local html/js file

We suggest you access web camera with [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2) control. It will provide a better experience. For accessing camera In UWP platfrom, you need enable Webcam capability in package mainifest file like Shawn Ramirez mentioned above.

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Please note if your web page use window.external.norify method, you must include the page's URI in the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest.for more please refer to [Interacting with web view content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/web-view#interacting-with-web-view-content)